# Converting a non-GUI Makefile (make) project to KDevelop

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, kdevelop

I have a rather simple C project I compile with make that I would like to run and debug in KDevelop, but I can't get this to work. I have installed cmake and tried both to import an existing project and start a new (which insists on creating a main.ccp file), but no matter what I do all the menu options to run the program are greyed out.

How can I move this project to KDevelop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiya, once you have created the new project by importing the custom makefile,
go to the Run Menu, Launch Configurations, then select the Global tag, then press the green plus sign +.

This will create a new launch configuration that you need to fill out with all of the correct executable paths and arguments and whatnot.

Once these are set, then the execute/debug options will ungrey out.

I had to figure this out today, was not obvious at all.